# any sense in having multiple, distinct puppet masters?

Tags: puppet, configuration-management, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I am wondering is whether it makes sense to have a single machine connect to multiple, distinct Puppetmaster instances.

My use case is that i have different privilege level I want to grant to server operators. We already operate a fairly (~100) wide array of Puppet clients connected to a single Puppetmaster, on which we use exported resources to configure Nagios, Munin, Backups and so on. Fairly standard stuff. But now we have another project where we setup a completely *separate* 
Puppetmaster for a client, as we didn't want to grant them access to our internal infrastructure. Yet we would like to import the exported resources on their servers into our monitoring infrastructure so that we can monitor their machines.

I guess another way to frame the question is: is it possible to run (multiple?) Puppet clients on a single machine, connected to multiple, distinct Puppetmasters?

Or would there be a way to share exported resources or data between Puppetmaster while limiting access?

> (I know that Puppet can be scaled horizontally by deploying [multiple
>   Puppetmaster servers in a load balancing
>   setup](https://serverfault.com/questions/458805/multiple-puppet-masters).
>   This question is *not* about that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing exported resources is problematic, because it requires mutual trust between the collecting master and the storing PuppetDB. For this you will need to share the Puppet CA, and this will blur the separation of the infrastructure.

You might have better luck actually introducing additional agents on the monitoring infrastructure as well. These will connect to the customer puppet master and collect only resources from there. You will then need to devise a way to generate a consistent configuration from the resources that two agents manage independently.

Comment: when you say "agents", do you mean `puppetd`, the puppet client running as a daemon (or a cronjob, actually)? is it even possible to run multiple puppetd clients on a single server?

Comment: @anarcat Yes. `puppetd` is a relic from 0.x and 2.x times. With version `3` or later you should only use `puppet agent` instead. They are the same. And yes, multiple instances can be separated, at least with recent versions. Make sure that each uses a distinct `confdir` and `vardir` setting. If this is unclear, feel free to make this a new question.